# As of May 8th, 2023, Community Building still appears as Moderators in Data Explorer Stack Exchange

Tags: feature-request

##### Update

I just posted about this in Meta Stack Exchange [Some sites names shown in Data Explorer Stack Exchange doesn't match the current site name. Is this a bug or a feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389022/1359324). Unfortunately, it was closed as a duplicate of a post from 2014 that also is closed as duplicate. The "final" post in the duplicate chain has 3 answers, but non of them works as an answer to this question. IMO, this post should stay here and as a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

##### Preface

I would greatly appreciate your assistance updating the site name "Moderators" to "Community Building" wherever it is displayed on [Data Explorer Stack Exchange](https://data.stackexchange.com). I have identified that it appears on the homepage and in the query page text field "Switch sites".  At this time, I don't know what other place someone might have to look to have an exhaustive list of all the relevant locations. I assume that a Staff member might do this job as they will be better equipped to do this efficiently.

This is not a duplicate of [Community Building doesn't exist in Data Explorer](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/225/7020;) on one side, the post is from 2015 but hasn't been answered. Reviewing the Stack Exchange history may not be necessary to determine if the site's absence was due to policies at that time, as many things have changed since then.

I apologize for the length of my message; I hope it will minimize the need for back-and-forth communication.

NOTE: A few hours after I posted this, I identified more sites, 3 graduated and 2 betas.

##### Chapter One: Data Explorer Stack Exchange for non power-users.

Data Explorer Stack Exchange is a site that lets it get data from Stack Overflow, and Stack Exchange sites data dumps, updated weekly. Users can compose queries to get data from one specific site or meta site. The user-created queries are publicly available. Any user, anonymous or signed in, can use queries created by others. At the bottom of the query page is the text field called "Switch sites" with autocomplete suggestions. The autocomplete is automatically turned on as the user types the second character. As the user continues typing, the autocomplete options are updated.

##### Chapter Two: How the issue was found

Yesterday I used the Site Activity and VoteGraph query created by rolfl to get that from Community Building. I found that the site name was not updated, but other sites that have changed the name show their current name. I.E., Software Engineering was originally named Programmers. It appears in the autocomplete options as Software Engineering. The same for many other sites that have changed their name. The [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286109/1359324) to [Was Programmers (now Software Engineering) the first SE site to change its name?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286108/1359324) shows a list of sites that have changed their name. The community maintains this list; It shows the current and past names; it includes Community Building.
Today, while writing this post, I looked at the Data Explorer Stack Exchange homepage and found that the old name, "Moderators", is shown instead of the new name, "Community Building".

##### Chapter Three: Why this post was created

I searched Meta Stack Exchange for posts mentioning that the text field *Switch sites* shows an old name instead of the new one, but I found nothing.

##### Conclusion

The request to update the site name shown in the Data Explorer Stack Exchange in locations like the homepage and the query text field *Switch Sites* should be a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), but it might be a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug). IMO the use of one or the other is irrelevant for end-users in this case; it depends on what works better for the Staff's internal process.

While it was found that the same issue happens to other sites, it's unclear how this should be handled. As the issue was found while writing an answer to a question from this site, I think this post belongs here. It's a Staff decision how this is handled internally.

##### Epilogue

Please update **this site name** in all the places that appear in Data Explorer Stack Exchange.

##### Addendum

###### Part 1

Data Explorer Stack Exchange
Community Building
[image: Data Explorer Stack Exchange - Community Building]

Site Activity and VoteGraph by rolfl
Top
[image: Site Activity and VoteGraph by rolfl - Top]
Bottom
[image: Site Activity and VoteGraph by rolfl - Top]

Autocomplete options

Co
[image: Autocomplete options - Co]

Comm
[image: Autocomplete options - Comm]

Mod
[image: Autocomplete options - Mod]

###### Part 2

I took a look at the Data Explorer Stack Exchange homepage. I identified some sites with a similar situation, the name shown is not the same as the site's current name.

| SEDE | Current Name |
| --- | --- |
| Musical Practice and Performance | Music: Practice & Theory |
| Health | Medical Sciences |
| Mythology | Mythology and Folklore |
| LEGO® Answers | Bricks |
| Statistical Analysis | Cross Validated |

Comment: I'd love to be able to do this on my own. It's bothered me for years. But, of those sites listed we are _by far_ the smallest community. It may be helpful to get some of those other communities to push for this update as well.

Comment: Thank @Andy. P.S. As I mentioned in the question, it's closed as duplicate of [Why hasn't Music.SE's name changed on data.stackexchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244356/1359324). I have already tried two times to reopen [Some sites names shown in Data Explorer Stack Exchange doesn't match the current site name. Is this a bug or a feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389022/1359324). Do you think that I should try a third time?